# Javascript - List all properties/methods from an object

Tags: javascript, constructor

I know that an object literal can have its keys listed by using `Object.keys()` method. But what about an object that was created through a constructor function?

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';
Foo.prototype.baz = 'baz';

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(Object.keys(foo).join(', ')); // returns ''
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo).join(', ')); // returns ''
```

Comment: The key in understanding is in the word `Own` in `getOwnPropertyNames`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` will only get **own** enumerable properties, and `getOwnPropertyNames` will only get **own** properties (even if not enumerable). Neither of them will give you the names of properties inherited from the prototype (or its prototype, or *its*, ...).

If you only care about *enumerable* properties, [see trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575562/157247).

If you want *all* of them,¹ even if they're not enumerable, you have to loop through the prototype chain:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  var result = [];
  while (obj && obj !== Object.prototype) {
    result.push.apply(result, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';
Foo.prototype.baz = 'baz';

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(getAllPropertyNames(foo));
```

In that example, I stopped when we reached `Object.prototype`, but of course you could keep going until you hit `null` instead:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  var result = [];
  while (obj) {
    result.push.apply(result, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';
Foo.prototype.baz = 'baz';

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(getAllPropertyNames(foo));
```

---

¹ *"If you want **all** of them..."* Note that in the above, we haven't tried to get properties that are named by [*Symbols*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type) instead of strings. If we did, we'd use `getOwnPropertySymbols` as well as `getOwnPropertyNames`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop:

```js
function Foo () {}

Foo.prototype.bar = 'bar';
Foo.prototype.baz = 'baz';

var foo = new Foo();

for (var key in foo)
  console.log(key, foo[key]);
```

Note that this has limitations. Some properties can be made non-enumerable, and will then not be included. This is for instance the case for the `length` property of arrays:

```js
var a = [1, 2];

for (var key in a)
  console.log(key, a[key]);
```